# Store school timetable values in database

Tags: mysql, timetable

I am able to design time table as shown in screen short.
[Screen Short](http://www.flickr.com/photos/110025772@N02/11101476955/)

**confusing part**: How to store teacher id in database which is stored in another table. I have decided to store in following format

Subject (already stored)

```
subject_id    subject_name       class_id      teacher_id
```

Time Table Master

```
tt_id     class_id
```

Time Table Data

```
ttd_id     tt_id      time      day     subject_id      teacher_id
```

Whereas timetable form only allows to select subject... how can I store teacher_id for each subject. Please guide me in right direction??

Comment: To me it looks like each instance of `subject` already knows which teacher it has assigned to it, am I right?

In that case I do not understand your question. Can you not just extract that data?

Comment: yes, i am not able to extract teacher id against each subject from subject table, so that i can store it in timetable_data table.

Comment: That should be quite trivial. The same way you parse `subject_id`, just parse `teacher_id` with it. Can we see some of your code?

Comment: each subject is assigned to particular teacher, whereas same teacher can teach multiple subjects in same class and it is already stored in subject table. while saving timetable it post subject ids so that it get relative teacher id from subject table and store it in timetable.

Comment: Why not assign a teacher to a subject instead? That way, the subject that you parse around in your script, will always know who is teaching the class at hand.

Comment: teacher already assigned. Well it is not about time table. Is it possible to extract an associated value from one table and store it in another table.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have mixed different types of data in your tables which is why it is confusing you. There is a difference between a Subject and a SubjectInstance.

A subject might include an id and name only (e.g. 2, English) whereas a SubjectInstance would be a subject on a particular day for a particular teacher and might have things like id, day, time, teacher, classroom. The day might be a foreign key to a Day table, the Teacher and Classroom might also be foreign keys to a Teacher and Classroom table.